# TTextLayout - What's the difference between RightToLeft and HorizontalAlign?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Setting TTextLayout.RightToLeft to True seems to be the same as setting TTextAlign.HorizontalAlign to TTextAlign.Trailing. So what's the point of RightToLeft? In fact they seem to reverse each other. If I set RightToLeft to True and HorizontalAlign to Trailing then the text is on the left again I was hoping that RightToLeft would cause the text to be written right to left as with Hebrew text, but this isn't the case. Does TTextLayout support Hebrew style right to left in any way?

Comment: Which Delphi version do you have? I recall `RightToLeft` did not work (was not implemented, and I still don't know whether it is implemented) for many years after `FMX` was introduced, for the correct purpose, that is display middle east languages properly written from right to left. Also, in VCL it required the OS to support these languages. The `HorizontalAlign` simply just define where the text in a control is placed. Of course the `RightToLeft` also swaps the meaning of  `HorizontalAlign'

Answer (score 3):

Your observations are not correct.

Use this demo: https://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/branches/RadStudio_XE6/Object%20Pascal/FireMonkey%20Desktop/TextLayoutDemo/. Add a line of text with an ending exclamation point such as "Hello World!". Then play with the settings. You'll see where the exclamation point goes.

Here is the result. The `|` is used to show left and right margins

```
Align=Left, RightToleft=FALSE
    |Hello World!                      |

Align=Right, RightToleft=FALSE
    |                      Hello World!|

Align=Left, RightToleft=TRUE
    |                      !Hello World|

Align=Right, RightToleft=TRUE
    |!Hello World                      |
```

Now why does it works like that? I think it is related to languages written from right to left (Arab) or from left to right (English).

Comment: Why you didn't get `!World Hello` ?

Comment: @Bosshoss Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks, that's the demo that I've been using. I hadn't tried with punctuation. It seems that this is only the case with punctuation at the end. I would have expected '!dlroW olleH' . It's almost like this feature is partially finished. I can't think of a reason you'd need it to behave like it does.

Comment: Maybe it makes sense with a right-to-left language instead of English. I have no experience in that domain.